# Select followers and connections that they are not followers in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a complicated query to resolve and I don't know how to get the correct results. First of all, let me show you the tables I have:

```
+------------+
| users      |
+------------+
| id         |
| first_name |
| last_name  |
+------------+

+--------------+
| clients      |
+--------------+
| id           |
| users_id     |
| uid          |
| access_token |
+--------------+

+---------------+
| users_follows |
+---------------+
| users_id      |
| follow_id     |
+---------------+

+-------------------+
| users_connections |
+-------------------+
| id                |
| users_id          |
| clients_id        |
| uid               |
| name              |
+-------------------+
```

Our website uses Facebook Connect, so EACH user connected has a client UID (Facebook UID). For a functionality of the website I need a query that does the next: select all the the people you follow (`users_id=ME`) plus the users_connections but if a users_connection is also someone I follow do not include it on the final result. Finally, for this rows if it's a "following" I need `users.first_name` and `users.last_name` and if it's a connection NOT registered on our website I need `users_connections.name`.

I will have a lot of rows an probably people can have a lot of people who follow so a NOT IN and id's concatenated I think that it's not the best way to scale it.

Can anyone bring me some light?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would really help if you provided sample data.  Your explanation does not particularly help someone not familiar with your specific domain.

Comment: @udexter you question is a little vague. about connections what do you want my connections or peoples connections whom i follow?